# Allow deleting questions with negative score

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, self-delete

Currently you can't delete your own question if it contains answers that were upvoted.

I propose there's an exception when the question is being downvoted, because if it is, it may need to be deleted.
Otherwise it goes against the spirit of removing bad content.

Comment: As an aside, when taking it into extremes: *"Is it ok for a user to remove all their contributions?"* at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37720/is-it-ok-for-a-user-to-remove-all-their-contributions

Comment: I bet you wish you could delete this question now... ;)

Comment: No, I do not wish that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason behind disallowing deletion for questions with upvoted answers is that the people who answer the question in good faith shouldn't lose the reward of turning a bad question into a good answer.

Further, even bad questions might yield good information we want to be found via google later.

If the question is closed, then the question can be deleted, and that's the proper path for a question with upvoted answers that should be deleted - close it, then two days later delete it.  In this way you have to have many people in agreement that as good as the answer is, the whole thing just needs to be chucked.

Once the OP submits their question to the community, if someone contributes something the community values, the OP loses the ability to get rid of the question.  This is by design.

Comment: If a question can be meaningfully and usefully answered (without changing the topic, obviously), then it isn’t a bad question in the first place and should not receive downvotes. A bad *question* can only be improved by editing the question; there is no such thing as “turning a bad question into a good answer”.

Answer (score 2):

Even bad questions can provide good content. That's the entire point of the [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) badge.

...and if we implement this I'll never get one. =(

Comment: http://sadtrombone.com

Comment: I'm not saying its mandatory to delete it, but that it should be possible

Comment: @Downvoter - In my experience, it's only the questions that are blatantly offensive and terrible ("how does I give virus to user if they try to reverse engineer my codez?") that get deleted. Such questions are rarely open long enough to get good answers.

Comment: You may be right there

Comment: Not building functionality with the aim of allowing/incentivizing people to get some specific badges does not seem like a good approach. The fact that this badge in question is not awarded anymore  ("This badge is retired and is no longer awarded.") could mean that in this specific case it was not a good idea ad all

Answer (score 1):

I am wholeheartedly for this.  It should be possible to vote to delete negative-score questions, regardless of whether they have been closed or answered.

There is no such thing as “turning a bad question into a good answer”: the phrase itself is nonsensical, a question can be answered, but cannot be turned into an answer.  A well-written answer can prove the question wasn’t as bad as it seemed at first, but even then, if a question amasses downvotes easily, it should probably be edited anyway to make it apparent it’s not as trivial and poorly thought out as it may seem (which gives question downvoters a chance to retract their votes).

For comparison: we withdraw reputation from users who had their suggested edits to deleted posts approved, on the basis that it is a waste of time to edit poor-quality posts, even if the edit itself is fine.  Similarly, we can say it is it is a waste of time to answer poor-quality qurstions, even if the answer itself is fine.

This will not only rid the site of poor content, but also reduce (answerers’) [incentives to answer poor questions](/a/387372/620615), (curators’) to strategically vote down answers that happen to answer poor questions, but with which there is little wrong otherwise, while creating incentives to edit questions themselves to improve their apparent quality (as remarked above).  And removes a few other perverse incentives as well (like spitefully downvoting askers).

Comment: "And removes a few other perverse incentives as well (like spitefully downvoting askers)" - how so? Wouldn't that only provide *more* incentive to do it, since the question would then be eligible for deletion regardless of the quality of its answers?

Comment: Spite: "a desire to hurt, annoy, or offend someone."... if you downvote because you disagree with the asker, it's spiteful. If you downvote because you think the question is bad enough (noisy, etc.) that it would be better if it was not present on the website at all (i.e. that it would be deleted), I'd argue is not spiteful.

Comment: Surely it actively encourages downvoting as a first step towards deletion.