# Linked question box showing same link multiple times

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions

I've seen the below happen on a couple of questions today - can't seem to find anybody else having reported it. Essentially, the same link is showing up multiple times as a linked question.

Seen today at [How do you delete stackexchange account and a question I submitted? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142848/213634):

[image: Twice linked]

Can also be seen [here - non duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7635/213634):

[image: Another twice linked, non duplicate]

Comment: Is this because the link appears twice? Once in the 'Duplicate header' and once in the answerer's body text?

Comment: @danielhanly.com Probably, but I'm still thinking it is a recently introduced bug. It would happen all the time if not - and it doesn't make sense to re-link the same question multiple times, that's just noise.

Comment: Normally, duplicates are only shown in the duplicate header. Because the answerer references the duplicated question directly, it doubles. I agree with you, it shouldn't happen, but this isn't an average case because Answerers don't always link to the duplicates.

Comment: @danielhanly.com I'm pretty sure I've seen it on other questions as well. Currently looking.

Comment: @danielhanly.com Another example added.

Comment: Well... that ruins my theory ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

Some recent changes to this code missed the original de-duplication logic.

Fixed in the next build (rev 2013.10.7.1049).